# Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1^\left (\sin^2x \right)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^\left (\sin^2x \right)}\right)^\left(\sin^2x \right) = ?$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{1^\left (\sin^2x \right)}+\frac{1}{2^\left (\sin^2x \right)}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^\left (\sin^2x \right)}\right)^\left(\sin^2x \right) = ?$$

This doesn't seem an indeterminate form to me so I directly substituted the value of x to evaluate the limit. Am I right?

Comment: Am I missing something or... if we plug $x=0$ we will get $(1 + 1 + ... + 1)^0$ = 1. Don't you mean $\lim_{\color{red}{n}\to 0}$ ?

Comment: That is exactly what was I doing. This is the question given to me. I will check again.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to0}$ doesn't make sense either. Perhaps $\lim_{n\to\infty}$? In which case, the expression is $\zeta(-\sin^2x)^{\sin^2x}$, so probably no closed form would exist

Comment: I think the expression is raised to $1/(\sin^2(x))$