# Trigonometric Limit tends to $\infty$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{\left(1^\left(\cot^2x \right)+2^\left(\cot^2x \right)+...+n^\left(\cot^2x \right)\right)^\left(\tan^2x \right)}$$

How to approach? Need hints.

Comment: @TheDeadLegend Answer is 1

Comment: Put $a=\cot^{2}x$ and then we know that $n^{a+1}/(1^{a}+2^{a}+\cdots +n^{a}) \to 1+a=\operatorname{cosec}^{2}x$

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I can't see how you got $n^{a+1}$in numerator,can you explain it please?

Comment: Hint: $1^{\cot^2 x} + 2^{\cot^2 x} + ... + n^{\cot^2 x} \leq n*n^{\cot^2 x} = n^{\cot^2 x + 1}$.

Comment: @Fawad: my comment is a hint and the result in my comment is standard one proved as limit of a Riemann sum and is valid if $a\neq 1$. Based on this the limit in question can be evaluated easily.

Comment: Answer is $0$ and not $1$ which can be checked by putting $x=\pi/4$.

Comment: The limit in my comment is valid for all $a\neq -1$. There was a typo in previous comment.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2266842/limit-lim-x-to-0-left-frac11-left-sin2x-right-cdots-frac1n

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment, the expression under limit can be expressed as $$\left(\frac{n^{a+1}}{1^{a}+2^{a}+\cdots +n^{a}} \right) ^{1/a}\cdot n^{-1/a}$$ where $a=\cot^{2}x$ and this clearly tends to $(a+1)^{1/a}\cdot 0=0$.

---

The question would be more interesting if presented as $$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{\operatorname{cosec}^{2}x}}{(1^{\tan^{2}x}+2^{\tan^{2}x}+\cdots+n^{\tan^{2}x})^{\cot^{2}x}}$$ The expression under limit operation tends to $(1+b)^{1/b}$ as $n\to\infty$ where $b=\tan^{2}x$. Next as $x\to 0$ the variable $b\to 0$ and therefore $(1+b)^{1/b}\to e$ so that final answer is $e$. Another variation which is more in line with the given question is $$\lim_{x\to 0}\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{\sec^{2}x}}{(1^{\cot^{2}x}+2^{\cot^{2}x}+\cdots+n^{\cot^{2}x})^{\tan^{2}x}}$$ and the final answer is then $1$.